# How export query result as CSV from a remote database with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, csv, linked-server

I’m doing the following query on a remote database:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = 
'SELECT ts, value
   FROM history
  WHERE name = ''SOME_ID''

EXEC (@SQL) AT SOME_LINKED_SERVER
```

So the expected output is like that:

```
ts       value
----------------
ts1     value1
ts2     value2
…      …
```

I’m doing this query for almost 100 different names and am willing to save a different CSV for each output. I know I can do it manually by clicking with the right button on the query’s output and selection “Save Result As...”, but it would take too long, specially because each query takes about 10 minutes to finish.

So I’d like to do it automatically, making the procedure export all the different CSV’s after getting the data. My ideia is to loop the search through an array of names, do the query and export the output as a CSV.

How can I do that? Before trying to loop through the array, I'm already struggling to output a CSV for a single query result.

Comment: Your best bet is to use an SSIS package, since that makes the output easy.

Answer (score 0):

Why do it one name at a time when you can do this:

```
SELECT [ts], [value], [name]
FROM [SOME_LINKED_SERVER].[database_name].[dbo].[history] H (NOLOCK)
WHERE [name] IN (<name list>)
```

If you want to store the result on the local end, then insert the data into a local table and work with the data there. Like so:

```
SELECT [ts], [value], [name]
INTO [local_history]
FROM [SOME_LINKED_SERVER].[database_name].[dbo].[history] H (NOLOCK)
WHERE [name] IN (<name list>)

SELECT * FROM [local_history] -- WHERE [name] = 'SOME_ID'
```

Then export, either by using Save Results As..., or copy and pasting the results into Excel, and doing a Save as... (F12).

Even better: if you have SSIS installed, use that to build a package that runs the query, and does the export for you. SSIS can even loop through the list of names if it comes down to that. If you don't have SSIS installed, install it, it comes with SQL Server. SSIS can be made to automate this process entirely.